# How to parse this json in List<Class>?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am developing windows form application in framework 4.0. I am using JSON.NET. I have the following json in a string variable. I have the 10 classes in the json as follows. How to parse the following json and convert it into List

```
[
        {
            "Class": 1,
            "ClassUrl": "EngineeringSemister12014A",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                }
            ],
            "IsArchived": true
        },
        {
            "Class": 7,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer2014A",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Class": 8,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer22014A",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer2",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Class": 9,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer32014A",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer3",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Class": 10,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer32014B",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer3",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 8,
                    "OEPTitle": "english"
                }
            ],
            "IsRecycled": true
        },
        {
            "Class": 12,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer52014B",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer5",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 8,
                    "OEPTitle": "english"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Class": 13,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer62014B",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer6",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 8,
                    "OEPTitle": "english"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Class": 16,
            "ClassUrl": "Mechanical2014undefined",
            "OEPTitle": "Mechanical Branch",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 6,
                    "OEPTitle": "history"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 4,
                    "OEPTitle": "chemical "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Class": 6,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer12014A",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer1",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 6,
                    "OEPTitle": "history"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 4,
                    "OEPTitle": "chemical "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Class": 11,
            "ClassUrl": "Engineer42014B",
            "OEPTitle": "Engineer4",
            "Subject": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "OEPTitle": "Algebra"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "OEPTitle": "Maths"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 6,
                    "OEPTitle": "history"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 4,
                    "OEPTitle": "chemical "
                },
                {
                    "Id": 8,
                    "OEPTitle": "english"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Do want to parse it and create a class? or what? Have you POCO class for your json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [*json2csharp*](http://json2csharp.com/):

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OEPTitle { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int Class { get; set; }
    public string ClassUrl { get; set; }
    public string OEPTitle { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subject { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
}
```

and now, you can use JSON.NET:

```
List<RootObject> rootObj = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(yourJsonHere);
```